# HTML XPath Searching by class name

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I Have a problem with xpath in c# 
I want to find all elements with this structure 
I have 10 links which all of them have this structure:

```
<div class="PartialSearchResults-item" data-zen="true">
<div class="PartialSearchResults-item-title">
<a class="PartialSearchResults-item-title-link result-link"target="_blank" href='https://www.google.com/'> Google</a>
    </div>
<p class="PartialSearchResults-item-url">www.google.com</p>
<p class="PartialSearchResults-item-abstract">Search the world.</p>
   </div>
```

for example with this sample i want to get "Google" and "www.google.com" and "Search the world."

```
var titles = hd.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class, 'PartialSearchResults-item')]");
string link;
foreach (HtmlNode node in titles){
string description = node.SelectSingleNode(".//*[contains(@class,'PartialSearchResults-item-abstract')]").InnerText;

link = node.SelectSingleNode(".//*[contains(@class,'PartialSearchResults-item-url')]").InnerText;

 string title = node.SelectSingleNode(".//a[contains(@class,'PartialSearchResults-item-title-link result-link')]").InnerText;}
```

But I get error null reference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is in the query where you are getting the `titles`. You are looking for div which's `class` attribute contains `PartialSearchResults-item`, which is your item's root node. But there is also other nodes which are satisfying to your query, for example the div with class `PartialSearchResults-item-title` also satisfying to your query. Then after selecting this 2 divs you are iterating over them and trying to get sum child nodes, for the first iteration your code will work fine, because you have right node, but in the second iteration you have the node with class `PartialSearchResults-item-title` which only have one `a`, so you will get `NullReferenceException` in the second iteration when you are querying for the description, because you are trying to get value of the `InnerText` property of `null` object

```
string description = node.SelectSingleNode(".//*[contains(@class,'PartialSearchResults-item-abstract')]").InnerText;
```

I would suggest to not use `contains`. In your case your root node has only one class `PartialSearchResults-item`, so you can query it like this

```
var titles = hd.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='PartialSearchResults-item']");
```

Comment: Your Solution is correct but i'm also stuck at same point and in my case, with class name `PartialSearchResults-item` (for eg.) i've other classes too. so not able to get result by using
    `var titles = hd.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='PartialSearchResults-item']");` 
for using this syntax i'need to give every class name alongwith which won't be fixed.